# Disconnect LAN computer from modem with admin priviliges (D-link Dir-300)

Tags: networking, router, lan, modem

i would like to know how to disconnect a persons computer from a local network when i have admin priviliges on the modem, the computer i wish to disconnect is connected to the modem by a LAN cable, im using "D-link Dir-300"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options

- Check for a feature called **MAC filtering**. You can block access by MAC address. I'd suggest doing the opposite though and only **allowing certain MACs**. This way, MAC spoofing won't work, unless they spoof one of your device MACs (which would cause conflicts and probably refuse connection anyways).

  [image]
- Check for an **access control** feature. It works similar to MAC filtering but you can specify which parts of the network are blocked, and optionally log all attempts:

  [image]
- Physically unplug the network cable

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, and much apreciated =)